# .JSchException: Packet corrupt

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I am using Jsch 0.1.51 on RHEl 6 with Jdk 1.7_51. While making session to a remote machine I am getting exception that is :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Packet corrupt
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.start_discard(Session.java:1049)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:919)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthNone.start(UserAuthNone.java:56)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:389)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at TestSFTP.checkException(TestSFTP.java:130)
        at TestSFTP.moveFileToDir(TestSFTP.java:78)
        at TestSFTP.main(TestSFTP.java:73)
```

Same code was working fine with RHEL 5. Can any body provide some suggestions .. Thanks

code used is :

```
Session   session     = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();

session = jsch.getSession(this.sftpUser,this.sftpHost,this.sftpPort);

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword(this.sftpPassword);
session.connect();
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
channelSftp.connect();
```

I am getting error at session.connect();

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: code added just now in question itself. Thanx for watching

Comment: Just come to know issue is with JDK 32 bit on RHEL 6 64 bit. I can not change my platform and JDK.. does Jsch provide some fix for such issue..?

Answer (score 10):

This exception can occur if you are trying to connect on an already existent session. A work around is closing the session and then starting a new session. This helped me. Found some help from this site:

http://flyingjxswithjava.blogspot.com/2015/03/comjcraftjschjschexception-packet.html

Quoting essential points from the site to understand the problem:

- This exception occurs when the Session is reused repeatedly in a loop where the session is disconnected intentionally or due to time out and needs to reconnect again.
- The reason that such an exception is thrown is that the first time the Session is connected to the remote site, a random number called Packet is generated for the session.
- When the thread is having its 1 hour sleep, the session gets automatically disconnected due to no activity for a certain period of time.
- When the Session is disconnected, the Packet is lost.
- When the Session is trying to reconnect, it could not find the Packet, thus the exception is thrown.