# keep on getting packet corrupt exception during session connect using jsch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am trying to sftp using JSch. however I am getting exception during `session.connect()` as below.

Using sftp server as Bitvise (personal edition)

**Noticed that this is working fine only for 3des-cbc and aes128-cbc encryption algorithms. When I chose any ctr algorithms (like aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr) in the server then only I am getting this issue.**

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Packet corrupt
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.start_discard(Session.java:1067)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:937)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthNone.start(UserAuthNone.java:56)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:396)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Is this a jsch bug

**Below is the log.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log>
  <start time="2017-11-28 10:57:02.441373 +0000" appName="BvSshServer" appVersion="7.35" thisFile="C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Server\Logs\BvSshServer20171128-105702440-P0000.log"/>

  <event seq="1" time="2017-11-28 10:57:02.440330 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION" desc="Configuration description.">
    <parameters configPart="ServerSettings"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:55:13.058180 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:54:39.857622 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:53:08.676523 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:50:46.160976 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:48:26.592495 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <settings>
      <powerShell><![CDATA[
        $cfg = new-object -com "BssCfg726.BssCfg726"

        $cfg.settings.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssGexSha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG15Sha512Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha256Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.aes256_cbc = $true
        $cfg.settings.session.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.session.maxTotalSessions = 600
        $cfg.settings.access.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.kerberos5Auth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.ntlmAuth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtAccount = "abdul"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtPassword.crypt = "0A957102C552FE8303FB90DCFFB1E782897160E44AEA6239D9DA39695EF9C32368661C3A33135CBF"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.group = "Virtual Users"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.loginAllowed = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.shellAccessType = 4 # $cfg.ShellAccessWD.powershell
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitScp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitSftp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.inheritMountPoints = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.realRootPath = "C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.useDefaultSfsHomeDir = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.sfsHomeDir = "/"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitC2S = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitS2C = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.NewCommit()

        $cfg.SaveServerSettings()
      ]]></powerShell>
    </settings>
  </event>

  <event seq="2" time="2017-11-28 10:57:02.441526 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION" desc="Configuration description.">
    <parameters configPart="HostKeys"/>
    <keypair algorithm="RSA" keyBits="3072" md5="2b:16:18:83:7b:c6:5e:49:f2:f0:8e:e2:dc:64:da:1a" babble="xutog-sabeg-tunur-gytin-sefal-mikus-gamat-zubeh-zozag-kepal-toxix" sha256="CiAWVUMB0+KqGRnwQ7/CwZiKSXLvnSVZOPvdjd+T+dM"/>
    <keypair algorithm="ECDSA/nistp384" keyBits="384" md5="6f:9d:1a:2f:6c:24:63:e8:ad:1e:06:f9:40:83:17:c4" babble="xucik-gotik-betib-sahit-lekud-labum-visid-natif-tysid-sosir-gixix" sha256="PtWOhG9HsoCfuFFCy4hxOwPW4QTTZohWe5UJ2OQ36dk"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="3" time="2017-11-28 10:57:02.692622 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_AUTO_ACCOUNT_ENABLED" desc="Enabled the automatically managed local account for virtual users.">
    <parameters account="BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="4" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.086919 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_SOCKET_BOUND" desc="Listening socket bound.">
    <parameters listenAddress="0.0.0.0:22" service="SSH"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="5" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.093938 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_FIREWALL_EXCEPTION_ADDED" desc="Windows Firewall exception added.">
    <parameters port="22" scope="Local" type="TCP/IPv4"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="6" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.096506 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_SOCKET_BOUND" desc="Listening socket bound.">
    <parameters listenAddress="[::]:22" service="SSH"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="7" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.103265 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_FIREWALL_EXCEPTION_ADDED" desc="Windows Firewall exception added.">
    <parameters port="22" scope="Local" type="TCP/IPv6"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="8" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.103669 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONF_SYNC_SETTINGS_DESCRIPTION" desc="Description of synchronization settings.">
    <settings>
      <powerShell><![CDATA[
        $cfg = new-object -com "BssCfg726.BssCfg726"

        $cfg.instance.SetDefaults()

        $cfg.InstanceType_SaveSettings()
      ]]></powerShell>
    </settings>
  </event>

  <event seq="9" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.103710 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONF_SYNC_SETTINGS_APPLIED" desc="Synchronization settings successfully applied."/>

  <event seq="10" time="2017-11-28 10:57:03.105654 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_STARTED" desc="Service started.">
    <parameters serviceAccount="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" sessionId="0" processId="11168" exePath="C:\Program Files\Bitvise SSH Server\BvSshServer.exe" cryptoProvider="Windows CNG (x64) with additions" bootTime="2017-11-10 06:32:59 +0000" computerName="DW7-ABDULL" computerSid="S-1-5-21-3842398330-100599899-1213948998" computerDomainName="CENTRAL" computerDnsDomainName="central.local" windowsVersion="6.1.7601 (64-bit)" servicePack="1" isDomainController="false" lsaProtection="0" lsaAuthPackages="msv1_0; BvLsaEx" bvLsaFileSize="321776" bvLsaLastInitTime="2017-11-10 06:32:40 +0000" bvLsaVersion="20.0.0.0"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="11" time="2017-11-28 10:57:07.398209 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_ACCEPTED" desc="Connection accepted.">
    <session id="1001" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59868"/>
    <parameters addressRule="AnyIP" listenAddress="127.0.0.1:22"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="12" time="2017-11-28 10:57:07.401015 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_VERSION_RECEIVED" desc="Client version string received.">
    <session id="1001" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59868"/>
    <parameters clientVersion="SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="13" time="2017-11-28 10:57:07.453490 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_KEY_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHMS" desc="Key exchange algorithms.">
    <session id="1001" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59868"/>
    <parameters kexAlg="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" cipherAlgIn="aes128-ctr" cipherAlgOut="aes128-ctr" macAlgIn="hmac-sha1" macAlgOut="hmac-sha1" comprAlgIn="zlib" comprAlgOut="zlib"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="14" time="2017-11-28 10:57:32.518050 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_DISCONNECTED_NORMALLY" desc="Session disconnected normally.">
    <session id="1001" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59868"/>
    <parameters disconnectReason="EofReceived"/>
    <help message="The client has disconnected the session by sending EOF."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="15" time="2017-11-28 10:57:32.599469 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_ACCEPTED" desc="Connection accepted.">
    <session id="1002" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59871"/>
    <parameters addressRule="AnyIP" listenAddress="127.0.0.1:22"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="16" time="2017-11-28 10:57:32.599907 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_VERSION_RECEIVED" desc="Client version string received.">
    <session id="1002" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59871"/>
    <parameters clientVersion="SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="17" time="2017-11-28 10:57:32.618462 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_KEY_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHMS" desc="Key exchange algorithms.">
    <session id="1002" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59871"/>
    <parameters kexAlg="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" cipherAlgIn="aes128-ctr" cipherAlgOut="aes128-ctr" macAlgIn="hmac-sha1" macAlgOut="hmac-sha1" comprAlgIn="zlib" comprAlgOut="zlib"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="18" time="2017-11-28 10:57:57.611643 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_DISCONNECTED_NORMALLY" desc="Session disconnected normally.">
    <session id="1002" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59871"/>
    <parameters disconnectReason="EofReceived"/>
    <help message="The client has disconnected the session by sending EOF."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="19" time="2017-11-28 10:58:12.691021 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION" desc="Configuration description.">
    <parameters configPart="ServerSettings"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 10:58:12.181097 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <settings>
      <powerShell><![CDATA[
        $cfg = new-object -com "BssCfg726.BssCfg726"

        $cfg.settings.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssGexSha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG15Sha512Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha256Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.aes256_cbc = $true
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.aes128_cbc = $true
        $cfg.settings.session.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.session.maxTotalSessions = 600
        $cfg.settings.access.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.kerberos5Auth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.ntlmAuth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtAccount = "abdul"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtPassword.crypt = "0A957102C552FE8303FB90DCFFB1E782897160E44AEA6239D9DA39695EF9C32368661C3A33135CBF"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.group = "Virtual Users"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.loginAllowed = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.shellAccessType = 4 # $cfg.ShellAccessWD.powershell
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitScp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitSftp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.inheritMountPoints = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.realRootPath = "C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.useDefaultSfsHomeDir = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.sfsHomeDir = "/"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitC2S = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitS2C = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.NewCommit()

        $cfg.SaveServerSettings()
      ]]></powerShell>
    </settings>
  </event>

  <event seq="20" time="2017-11-28 10:58:12.698356 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_RELOAD_SUCCESS" desc="Configuration reloaded successfully.">
    <parameters configPart="ServerSettings"/>
    <help message="Reloaded settings have been applied."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="21" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.687912 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_ACCEPTED" desc="Connection accepted.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880"/>
    <parameters addressRule="AnyIP" listenAddress="127.0.0.1:22"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="22" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.688506 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_VERSION_RECEIVED" desc="Client version string received.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880"/>
    <parameters clientVersion="SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="23" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.706426 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_KEY_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHMS" desc="Key exchange algorithms.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880"/>
    <parameters kexAlg="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" cipherAlgIn="aes128-cbc" cipherAlgOut="aes128-cbc" macAlgIn="hmac-sha1" macAlgOut="hmac-sha1" comprAlgIn="zlib" comprAlgOut="zlib"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="24" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.763753 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_LOGON_AUTH_SUCCEEDED" desc="User authentication succeeded.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <authentication attemptNr="1" userName="abdul" method="password"/>
    <parameters accountSettings="abdul" groupSettings="Virtual Users" tokenType="LogonUser" tokenLogonType="Network"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="25" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.771364 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CHANNEL_SESSION_OPENED" desc="Session channel opened.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="26" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.840991 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SFTP_SERVER_VERSION_NEGOTIATED" desc="SFTP protocol version negotiated.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
    <parameters versionRequested="3" versionSelected="3"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="27" time="2017-11-28 10:58:14.843764 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SFS_GET_FILE_STATUS" desc="Virtual filesystem: get file status.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
    <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="24200" desc="Getting file status failed.">
      <parameters path="C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD\largefile.txt.temp" flags="0x8000002F" statusCode="NoSuchFile"/>
      <error type="WinApi" operation="CreateFile()" code="2" message="The system cannot find the file specified."/>
    </sfs>
  </event>

  <event seq="28" time="2017-11-28 10:58:19.982707 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SFS_TRANSFER_FILE" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
    <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">
      <parameters path="C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD\largefile.txt.temp" timeMs="5145" bytesRead="0" bytesWritten="67487504" readRangeOffset="0" readRangeLength="0" writeRangeOffset="0" writeRangeLength="67487504" createdNewFile="true" resizedFile="false" endedBy="Client"/>
      <help message="File transfer ended by client."/>
    </sfs>
  </event>

  <event seq="29" time="2017-11-28 10:58:19.983699 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SFS_GET_FILE_STATUS" desc="Virtual filesystem: get file status.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
    <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="24000" desc="Getting file status succeeded.">
      <parameters path="C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD\largefile.txt.temp" how="NoFollow" flags="0x8000002F" partialFailure="false"/>
    </sfs>
  </event>

  <event seq="30" time="2017-11-28 10:58:19.994790 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SFS_RENAME_PATH" desc="Virtual filesystem: rename path.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
    <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="32000" desc="Renaming path succeeded.">
      <parameters oldPath="C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD\largefile.txt.temp" newPath="C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD\largefile.txt" flags="0x3"/>
    </sfs>
  </event>

  <event seq="31" time="2017-11-28 10:58:20.105301 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CHANNEL_SESSION_CLOSED" desc="Session channel closed.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <channel type="session" id="1"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="32" time="2017-11-28 10:58:20.105456 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_DISCONNECTED_NORMALLY" desc="Session disconnected normally.">
    <session id="1003" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59880" virtualAccount="abdul" windowsAccount="DW7-ABDULL\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
    <parameters disconnectReason="EofReceived"/>
    <help message="The client has disconnected the session by sending EOF."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="33" time="2017-11-28 11:15:28.339452 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION" desc="Configuration description.">
    <parameters configPart="ServerSettings"/>
    <change time="2017-11-28 11:15:27.807306 +0000" action="Settings edited via local Advanced Settings interface by 'CENTRAL\abdull'." process="BssCtrl.exe"/>
    <settings>
      <powerShell><![CDATA[
        $cfg = new-object -com "BssCfg726.BssCfg726"

        $cfg.settings.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssGexSha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG15Sha512Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha256Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.kex.gssG14Sha1Krb5 = $false
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.algs.encr.aes256_cbc = $true
        $cfg.settings.session.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.session.maxTotalSessions = 600
        $cfg.settings.access.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.kerberos5Auth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.ntlmAuth = 1 # $cfg.AuthDispND.disabled
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtAccount = "abdul"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.virtPassword.crypt = "0A957102C552FE8303FB90DCFFB1E782897160E44AEA6239D9DA39695EF9C32368661C3A33135CBF"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.group = "Virtual Users"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.loginAllowed = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.term.shellAccessType = 4 # $cfg.ShellAccessWD.powershell
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitScp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.permitSftp = 1 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.inheritMountPoints = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.new.realRootPath = "C:\Users\abdull\Desktop\FCAD"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.useDefaultSfsHomeDir = $false
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.xfer.sfsHomeDir = "/"
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.SetDefaults()
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitC2S = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.new.fwding.permitS2C = 2 # $cfg.DefaultYesNo.no
        $cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.NewCommit()

        $cfg.SaveServerSettings()
      ]]></powerShell>
    </settings>
  </event>

  <event seq="34" time="2017-11-28 11:15:28.347338 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SERVICE_CONFIG_RELOAD_SUCCESS" desc="Configuration reloaded successfully.">
    <parameters configPart="ServerSettings"/>
    <help message="Reloaded settings have been applied."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="35" time="2017-11-28 11:15:30.038971 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_ACCEPTED" desc="Connection accepted.">
    <session id="1004" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59943"/>
    <parameters addressRule="AnyIP" listenAddress="127.0.0.1:22"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="36" time="2017-11-28 11:15:30.040091 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_VERSION_RECEIVED" desc="Client version string received.">
    <session id="1004" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59943"/>
    <parameters clientVersion="SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="37" time="2017-11-28 11:15:30.063779 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_KEY_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHMS" desc="Key exchange algorithms.">
    <session id="1004" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59943"/>
    <parameters kexAlg="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" cipherAlgIn="aes128-ctr" cipherAlgOut="aes128-ctr" macAlgIn="hmac-sha1" macAlgOut="hmac-sha1" comprAlgIn="zlib" comprAlgOut="zlib"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="38" time="2017-11-28 11:15:55.056124 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_DISCONNECTED_NORMALLY" desc="Session disconnected normally.">
    <session id="1004" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59943"/>
    <parameters disconnectReason="EofReceived"/>
    <help message="The client has disconnected the session by sending EOF."/>
  </event>

  <event seq="39" time="2017-11-28 11:15:55.137667 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_ACCEPTED" desc="Connection accepted.">
    <session id="1005" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59944"/>
    <parameters addressRule="AnyIP" listenAddress="127.0.0.1:22"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="40" time="2017-11-28 11:15:55.138109 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_CONNECT_VERSION_RECEIVED" desc="Client version string received.">
    <session id="1005" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59944"/>
    <parameters clientVersion="SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="41" time="2017-11-28 11:15:55.153344 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_KEY_EXCHANGE_ALGORITHMS" desc="Key exchange algorithms.">
    <session id="1005" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59944"/>
    <parameters kexAlg="diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1" cipherAlgIn="aes128-ctr" cipherAlgOut="aes128-ctr" macAlgIn="hmac-sha1" macAlgOut="hmac-sha1" comprAlgIn="zlib" comprAlgOut="zlib"/>
  </event>

  <event seq="42" time="2017-11-28 11:16:20.067774 +0000" app="BvSshServer 7.35" name="I_SESSION_DISCONNECTED_NORMALLY" desc="Session disconnected normally.">
    <session id="1005" service="SSH" remoteAddress="127.0.0.1:59944"/>
    <parameters disconnectReason="EofReceived"/>
    <help message="The client has disconnected the session by sending EOF."/>
  </event>
</log>
```

Comment: JSch log file please.

Comment: FYI ... Just noticed that this is working fine only for 3des-cbc and aes128-cbc encryption algorithms. When I chose any ctr algorithms (like aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr) in the server then only I am getting this issue.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl any idea on this why this behavior?

Comment: I have asked for JSch log file.

Comment: I have attached the log file from server. I dont have a JSch log file. Since I am using JSch library from ColdFusion application I want to implement the com.jcraft.jsch.Logger interface in coldfusion to get the JSch log file. But that is very difficult and dont want to go with that.  No other way around??

Comment: I do not see any useful information in the server log. You can try to implement a test application in pure Java to debug this.

Comment: This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534307/how-to-decide-the-list-of-ciphers-to-be-used-in-jsch-library is related to this question. But , since it is different topic i created a new thread. Would you please help me answer that? . Probably , it will help me solve this.

Comment: Did you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838523/jschexception-packet-corrupt