# How to decide the list of Ciphers to be used in JSch library

Tags: java, encryption, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch version (jsch-0.1.54) and Bitvise SSH personal edition as sftp server on my local machine.

Currently I have provided all the ciphers in the code as given in the JSch documentation (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) as below.

```
session.setConfig("cipher.s2c", "blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256");
session.setConfig("cipher.c2s", "blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256");
```

And when I connected to the server I found that only the below algorithms (given against "Remote List" in the error node) are accepted (This is my understanding from the log file).

```
<error type="Flow" component="SshManager/transport" class="LocalSshDisconn" code="KeyExchangeFailed" description="FlowSshTransport: no mutually supported inbound encryption algorithm. Local list: aes256-gcm,aes128-gcm,aes256-cbc. Remote list: blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128."/>
```

In the server I didnt chose any of these algorithms and this led to an "Algorithm Negotiation Fail" error as expected.

So my question is - Whether these list of acceptable algorithms vary or not based on different environment (Testing Environment , UAT , Production etc..) and some server settings (some sftp server settings)?.

If this doesnt vary then I can hard code those algorithms in the code.Right??. But If it vary then how I need to handle it in the code so that no "Algorithm negotiation Fail" error?.

Comment: so , it may vary based on Java version in different environments??

Comment: Not on Java version, but rather on presence of JCE. See the [answer by @Mahran ALSHIEKH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17989883/850848#20072135).

Comment: How to check the presence of JCE in different environments. Is there any way?

Comment: I do not know how.

Comment: configure the server to support aes128-cbc. [This](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) appears to be a superior product to jsch and may support aes128-gcm.

Comment: @JamesKPolk ... Is there any way (I mean programmatically) to know the list of algorithms configured in the server. Why I am asking this is because the server control is not in our hand. But I know we can ask server administrator to know this. But just checking if there is any way to get that list programmatically or from any ftp client tool?.

Comment: sorry, I don't know.